# wxPython CSheet issue and replacement

Tags: wxpython

I want to add spreadsheet functionality to my wxpython application running on Windows. The CSheet module seems broken in the latest 2.9 version. It shows:
TypeError: EndEdit() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

May I know if there is any suggestions to fix it or any other python module with good spreadsheet functionality ? I tried some but most of them are built on top of CSheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSheet appears to just be a sub-class of Grid, so you could probably just use the Grid widget. Or you could go to wxPython's bug tracker on their website and submit this as a bug. They're usually pretty quick about patching stuff, especially in the 2.9 branch.