# wxPython CSheet PaintBackground() and EndEdit() errors

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I've been trying to use Python v2.7.11 and wxPython v3.0.2.0 to create a spreadsheet app. I am able to create and show the spreadsheet, but whenever I enter something (text, numbers, etc.) into a cell python throws 2 errors:

```
TypeError: PaintBackground() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
TypeError: PaintBackground() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

and then when I change cells (via arrow keys or mouse), it throws another error:

```
TypeError: EndEdit() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Whatever I entered into the cell is not preserved (the cell remains blank).

I've seen these errors mentioned, for example [here](https://github.com/manns/pyspread/issues/88) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778593/wxpython-csheet-issue-and-replacement), but neither addresses my specific problem. I've searched a lot and can't seem to find a solution to this. Any help is appreciated, my code is below.

**Spreadsheet class:**

```
from wx.lib.sheet import CSheet


class FFSpreadSheet(CSheet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FFSpreadSheet, self).__init__(parent)
        self._row = self._col = 0
        self.SetNumberRows(55)
        self.SetNumberCols(25)

        for i in xrange(55):
            self.SetRowSize(i, 20)

    def OnGridSelectCell(self, event):
        self._row, self._col = event.GetRow(), event.GetCol()
        control = self.GetParent().GetParent()._position
        value = self.GetColLabelValue(self._col) + self.GetRowLabelValue(self._row)
        control.SetValue(value)
        event.Skip()
```

**Frame class:**

```
import wx
from ffspreadsheet import FFSpreadSheet


class FFMainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        super(FFMainFrame, self).__init__(parent, -1, title, size=(550, 500))

        self._mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self._mainsizer)

        self._toolbar2 = wx.ToolBar(self, wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.TB_TEXT)
        self._position = wx.TextCtrl(self._toolbar2)
        self._toolbar2.AddControl(self._position)
        self._toolbar2.Realize()

        self._notebook = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=wx.RIGHT)

        self._sheets = [FFSpreadSheet(self._notebook),
                        FFSpreadSheet(self._notebook),
                        FFSpreadSheet(self._notebook)]
        self._sheets[0].SetFocus()

        self._notebook.AddPage(self._sheets[0], 'Sheet 1')
        self._notebook.AddPage(self._sheets[1], 'Sheet 2')
        self._notebook.AddPage(self._sheets[2], 'Sheet 3')

        self._mainsizer.Add(self._toolbar2)
        self._mainsizer.Add(self._notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.Center()
        self.Show()
```

**App class:**

```
import wx
from ffmainframe import FFMainFrame


class FitFit(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self._mainframe = FFMainFrame(None, -1, 'FitFit')
        return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = FitFit()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2012, the `PaintBackground()` method received a new argument: the device context.

```
     def PaintBackground(*args, **kwargs):
-        """PaintBackground(self, Rect rectCell, GridCellAttr attr)"""
+        """PaintBackground(self, DC dc, Rect rectCell, GridCellAttr attr)"""
```

The `CSheet` class has not been updated since 2003. Therefore, it is broken now. It can be still used as a code reference.

I think that your example was inspired by my tutorial. Recently, it has been updated; the example with the sheets as well. The `CSheet` has been dropped and `wx.grid.Grid` used instead.

http://zetcode.com/wxpython/skeletons/